# Force commands to run in parallel even without -j?

Tags: gnu-make

I know that if I put this in my `Makefile`

```
a: b c
```

Then run `make -j2 a` then it will run `b` and `c` in parallel, but what if I *always* want `b` and `c` to run in parallel, even if the user doesn't include -j >= 2?

In my scenario, `b` and `c` are actually daemons that never complete, so I need them to run in parallel. I don't want them to run in the background either.

Comment: If you can't run `b` or `c` by themselves, then they shouldn't be in separate rules.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Huh..who said you couldn't run them by themselves? You can run them independently but I want another command/target to run them simultaneously.

Comment: So nothing actually *built* by the targets `b` and `c`? They're just
`.PHONY`-ies for running commands?

Comment: @MikeKinghan In my scenario, `b` continuously builds and `c` continuously uploads. They're both PHONY.

Answer (score 0):

It's an odd use of `make`, but if you want to do it with `make`,
given that `b` and `c` are `.PHONY`, you could do so like:

```
.PHONY: a b c

a:
    $(MAKE) -j2 b c

b c:
    while [ "1" ]; do echo "$@: $$(date)"; sleep 1; done
```

A rule:

```
a: b c
```

isn't to the purpose. It says that `a` depends on `b` (being done) and
`a` depends on `c` (being done), but you don't want that at all. You
just want `a` to denote the concurrent execution of the recipes for
`b` and `c`.

You get:

```
$ make b
while [ "1" ]; do echo "b: $(date)"; sleep 1; done
b: Wed Mar  9 18:29:55 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:29:56 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:29:57 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:29:58 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:29:59 GMT 2016
^CMakefile:7: recipe for target 'b' failed
make: *** [b] Interrupt

$ make c
while [ "1" ]; do echo "c: $(date)"; sleep 1; done
c: Wed Mar  9 18:30:38 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:30:39 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:30:40 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:30:41 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:30:42 GMT 2016
^CMakefile:7: recipe for target 'c' failed
make: *** [c] Interrupt

$ make a
make -j2 b c
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/imk/develop/so/parallel_make'
while [ "1" ]; do echo "b: $(date)"; sleep 1; done
while [ "1" ]; do echo "c: $(date)"; sleep 1; done
b: Wed Mar  9 18:31:13 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:31:13 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:31:14 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:31:14 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:31:15 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:31:15 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:31:16 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:31:16 GMT 2016
b: Wed Mar  9 18:31:17 GMT 2016
c: Wed Mar  9 18:31:17 GMT 2016
^CMakefile:7: recipe for target 'b' failed
make[1]: *** [b] Interrupt
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'c' failed
make[1]: *** [c] Interrupt
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'a' failed
make: *** [a] Interrupt
```